# PayPal integration with wrong information then also get approved payment using card

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on `PayPal` integration with Objective C. I have done the integration of PayPal `iOS SDK 2.12.9`. My app is working fine with payment using Email, But i face the problem while i am using payment with credit card. I am insert current card number and incorrect expire date and security code then also i got successful payment like "**PayPal Payment Success!**". I got the following `JSON` response.

Here is your proof of payment:

```
{
    client =     {
        environment = sandbox;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.12.9";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2016-01-08T05:36:38Z";
        id = "PAY-69U983095T027654TK2HUVZQ";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
```

But i think this will not happens because i am inserting the wrong expire date and security code. Is there any solution for validate the expire date and security or any authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    client =     {
        environment = sandbox;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.12.9";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2016-01-08T05:36:38Z";
        id = "PAY-69U983095T027654TK2HUVZQ";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
```

The response clearly says you are in sandbox environment.And that will accept any valid email address ..You need to change the sandbox environment to Production.

[Paypal Distribution Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/)